# Sending multiple arrays with jQuery .post()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, .post

I have looked and can't quite come up with an answer to this question. I currently have an array which I call dataArray. The dataArray contains 2 keys (name, value) and is set up like this:
`dataArray.push({name : file.name, value : this.result});` 
I am passing this array to my PHP file using the .post() method like so:
`$.post('upload.php', dataArray[index], function(data) {}`. 
Then in the upload.php file I retrieve the data using:

```
$file = $_POST['value'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

This works fine for what I need. My question is how do I pass and retrieve 2 separate arrays. I have another array called 'position' that I would also like to send using the .post() method. This array is set up like so:
`position.push({left : 0, top : 0});` 
I can't seem to find a way to pass them both at the same time.

Comment: Use json to send data.

Answer (score 2):

You can always pass an javascript object with 2 arrays in it...

Like this:

```
arrayData= {
    array1 = [],
    array2 = []
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://post.url',
    data: arrayData
});
```

Retrieve in php script like this:

```
$arrayData = $_POST['arrayData'];
foreach($arrayData as $value) {
    //$value['array1']
    //$value['array2']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do something like:

```
dataArray.push({left:0,top:0};
```

Based on the pattern you have shown you should then be able to retrieve the values with:

```
$left = $_POST['left'];
$right= $_POST['right'];
```